# How to deal with 'require' of files bloating up my javascript with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, webpack-2, code-splitting

I am using Webpack to pull in `.svg` files which I can inline and use inside my Javascript components. It looks something like this:

```
export default class Svg {
    constructor() {
        const icons = require.context('public/images/svg', true, /\.svg$/);
    }
}
```

It works perfectly fine. Looking at the buildfile from Webpack I can see that all of these `.svg` files are being put inside of my main `app.js` javascript file.

This bloats up my Javascript file that every user on the website needs to load. Although this is only a one time load it does add up to the initial load when someone has not cached the file yet, or when it is refreshed because of changes.

I know that only at buildtime the javascript has access to the filesystem through node.js and therefore there is probably no way around this.

How do I combat the bloat of this file though?

To my knowledge there are a couple of options:

- Use XHR request to retrieve the data. This might be slow and cause flashes of icons that are not loaded in time. This might be do-able if you were to have something fast like elasticsearch but otherwise probably not feasible.
- Put all my `.svg` files into a separate file with Webpack so they will be cached longer because this files gets touched way less often than the main javascript code.
- Use code splitting to split up my `.svg. files and put each`.svg` file into a module of its own. Then let webpack deal with it by injecting the modules asynchronously when needed.

The last approach would probably only be helpful for components and javascript code that is not directly visible since there will be loadtime?

Because not all `.svg` files are necessary the first step would be to remove the `require.context` and import only files that are needed.

Any thoughts on how to deal with this? Would love to hear from someone who might have some experience on this. Otherwise any and all suggestions are welcome as well. :)

Comment: Did you mean: url-loader

Comment: i have this exact issue and im struggling to find an anwser